# Discrete Probability Camera Factory

Tags: probability

At a camera factory, an inspector painstakingly checks 20 cameras and finds that three of them need adjustment before they can be shipped. Another employee mixes the cameras so up so that no one knows which is which. The Inspector must recheck the cameras one at a time until he locates all the bad ones:
1- What is the probability that no more than 17 cameras need to be rechecked?
2- What is the probability that exactly 17 must be rechecked?

How would I go about even setting up for this problem? I've tried a few formulas but haven't gotten anywhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For not more than $17$ cameras to need to be rechecked, the $3$ bad ones must be among the first $17$. All $\binom{20}3$ sets of positions for the bad cameras are equally likely, and $\binom{17}3$ of them are favourable, so the probability for this is

$$
\frac{\binom{17}3}{\binom{20}3}=\frac{34}{57}\;.
$$

For exactly $17$ cameras to need to be rechecked, the $17$-th must be a bad one, with probability $\frac3{20}$, and if so, the remaining $2$ bad ones can be in $\binom{19}2$ equally likely sets of positions, of which $\binom{16}2$ are favourable, so the probability is

$$
\frac3{20}\cdot\frac{\binom{16}2}{\binom{19}2}=\frac2{19}\;.
$$

Answer (score 0):

Start with the last camera. No matter what, it does not need to be checked if is good or bad, as the Inspector only needs to subtract the cameras already inspected from the population as a whole. So, after examining 19 cameras, if two are bad, then the one left must also be bad. This can be extended to multiple cameras, if they are all of the same type; for example, if the Inspector has found the three bad cameras without inspecting the whole population, he knows the rest are good. So one just needs to find the probability of finding a run of n cameras all good/all bad before finding one that is different from the run.

Or, to run time forwards, once the Inspector has inspected the (n+1)th camera from the end, he knows the rest, as they are either all good or all bad, and so he has inspected (20-n) cameras in total.

That should set things up. (If it helps, take seventeen black cards and three red ones from a deck of playing cards, shuffle them, place them all face down in a row, and turn them over one by one starting from the left. That's an identical problem.)